# How do I make a field dynamically populated using a loop based on other fields in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data field names consists of letter number combinations that looks something like this.

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0
0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0
```

There will always be the same number of header fields within each letter. So in the above, if there were a "D" field, there would be D1 D2 D3 D4... The same would apply to the number, if it went up to 5 then all the letters would be up to 5. Each letter field group can only have a 1 in one of the field positions.

I would like create an additional column for each letter that indicates which header number the 1 appears in. So in the above example I would like to have the following fields added

```
A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Cat_A | Cat_B | Cat_C
0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |   4   |   1   |  0
0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 0  | 0  |   2   |   3   |  2
```

```
# X_cols captures all the fields that have a letter and number in the event there are other fields I want to ignore
X = df.filter(regex='^[a-zA-Z][0-9]') 
X_cols = X.columns.tolist()

# element_count captures the largest number for each letter category to be used in a loop
# Categories captures all the unique letters in the fields
element_count = pd.to_numeric(X.columns.str[1].max()) 
categories = X.columns.str[0].unique()

# Original thinking is to create a loop that basically replicates each field but only puts in the numerical value for the 1 position. So Cat_A4 would get a 4 and A1,A2,A3 would be blank. I would then collapse all the letter fields into single letter fields using sum. So Cat_A would be the sum of A1-A4 and so one for each letter category.

# this is the current loop but doesn't do what I want
for cat in categories:
    col_list=[]
    for element in range(1,element_count+1):
        col_list.append(f'{cat}{element}')
        df[f'cat_{cat}{element}'] = df[f'{cat}{element}'].apply(lambda x: element if x==1 else '')
        df[f'cat_{cat}'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)
```

Any help to solve this would be great. It does not have to be my approach to get to the final result which is simply a single new field for each category letter indicating where the "1" appeared

Comment: There is probably a pivot or something that would work well. Not sure though

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the result in a dictionary rather than a data frame

```
import pandas as pd

dat=pd.DataFrame({"A1":[0,0],
              "A2":[0,1],
              "A3":[0,0],
              "A4":[1,0],
              "B1":[1,0],
              "B2":[0,0],
              "B3":[0,1],
              "B4":[0,0],
              "C1":[0,0],
              "C2":[0,1],
              "C3":[0,0],
              "C4":[0,0]})
x=dat.columns[dat.apply(lambda x: any(x.eq(1)), 0)].tolist()

mydict={}
for j in x:
    letter=list(j)[0]
    i=list(j)[1]
    if mydict.get(letter)==None:
        mydict[letter]=i
    else:
        mydict[letter]=[mydict[letter], i]

print(mydict)
```

output

```
{'A': ['2', '4'], 'B': ['1', '3'], 'C': '2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your rows are in 0 and 1 format, you can use them as indices to index your column names:

```
col_srs = pd.Series(df.keys())

# you can later replace this single row operation with df.iterrows
row = df.iloc[0]
col_idx = [True if x==1 else False for x in list(row)]
result = list(col_srs.loc[col_idx].str[-1])
```

You'll probably want to save your results in a list during your iterrows, then pd.concat everything.